# Linq query to return country as column and cities as rows and count in cells

Tags: c#, sql, linq, binding, datagrid

I have this table in db :

```
| Buyer Country|  City  |... 
|:-------------|-------:|... 
|   Uk         | Lisbon |... 
| Portugal     | London |... 
|  France      | Madrid |... 
|  France      | Lisbon |... 
|  France      | Madrid |... 
|  France      | Madrid |...
```

And i would like to get a linq query that could give me this information so that i can bind it with a data grid like this :

```
| Buyer Country| Madrid | Lisbon | London |
|:-------------|-------:|-------:|-------:|
|   Uk         |   0    |    1   |   0    |
| Portugal     |   1    |    0   |   1    |
|  France      |   3    |    1   |   0    |
```

Countries and cities are dynamic to i cannot create them manually.
Basically i want to get the list of all buyers country in the first row and the number of times that country bought in that city in the form of columns by city.

The best i got was this :

```
            var query = from purchase in db.TotalPurchases
                    group purchase by new { purchase.Country, purchase.City } into grp
                    select new
                    {
                        country = grp.Key.Country,
                        city = grp.Key.City,
                        count = grp.Count(),
                    };
```

But this is not quite what i want :/

Comment: Why not? You only need to add entries to your result for those pairs of (country, city) which are not found in the db, don't you?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part with binding with the data grid.

Comment: Yea :/ i know i have all my information that way but i would like to bind this query directly with the datagrid, it should be a way to achieve this right? Or maybe i'm just thinking this the wrong way...

Comment: It looks to me like you want a classic cross tab query. Search for doing cross tab in LINQ and you should find some examples of how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a "pivot table" from your database table to bind to a grid view, the easiest way I know of is to use a `DataTable` as the binding source and use a LINQ query to get the information to populate it.

So we basically need to turn the unique row values for the "City" column into columns of the new pivot data table. We can do this in a few ways, but each of them requires a number of steps. The sample below shows a way that only requires a single query to the database to retrieve the data that we need.

```
// 1. Query for all data we need
var pivotInput = db.TotalPurchases
    .GroupBy(p => p.Country)
    .Select(cp => new {
            Country = cp.Key,
            PurchasesByCity = cp.GroupBy(x => x.City).Select(c => new {
                City = c.Key,
                NumberOfPurchases = c.Count()
            })
        }).ToList();

// 2. Get all distinct cities
var allCities = pivotInput
    .SelectMany(x => x.PurchasesByCity.Select(c => c.City))
    .Distinct().ToList();

// 3. Build the pivot data table "schema".
var pivotTable = new DataTable("purchasesByCity");
pivotTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Country", typeof(string)));
allCities.ForEach(c => pivotTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(c, typeof(int))));

// 4. Add as rows to the datatable
foreach (var c in pivotInput)
{
    var row = pivotTable.NewRow();
    row["Country"] = c.Country;
    foreach (var city in c.PurchasesByCity)
        row[city.City] = city.NumberOfPurchases;
    pivotTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you both Alex and Joseph Gagliardo, Alex you saved me lots of time searching on how to do this, im deeply thankful for your answers :). Alex this code will scale well if my table has a huge amount of data right, since the query we get from the database will already have the data sorted out by city and country, so the memory usage on my side will be dependent on how many different cities i have on my database correct? i would like to vote your answer up but dont have yet 15 points, thank you :)